# AngularJS Directive for ElevateZoom jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use the [ElevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) jQuery plugin inside an angular app.

Essentially, to use ElevateZoom normally, you create an image as follows:

```
<img id="my-img" src="small.jpg" data-zoom-image="big.jpg" />
```

Then in your application JS:

```
$('#my-img').elevateZoom(options);
```

This works fine in a standard app. But when I try and do it in my AngularJS app using a directive (I followed some SO answers for getting jquery plugins into angular with directives) I just can't make it work.

**Live editable demo on Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mu4EOcGtGs7XVDDUvnnB?p=preview**

My directive looks like:

```
app.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    compile: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).elevateZoom(scope.$eval(attrs.elevateZoom));
    }
  };
});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<img ng-elevate-zoom ng-src="{{small_image}}" data-zoom-image="{{large_image}}" />
```

What am I doing wrong? I've only been experimenting with Angular a few days so go easy on me ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your directive:

```
app.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    compile: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).elevateZoom(scope.$eval(attrs.elevateZoom));
    }
  };
});
```

Keep in mind that `compile` function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) { ... }  dont have access to scope, so I guess you were trying to use the `link` function.

Check [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile)

I did some changes:

**HTML**

```
<img ng-elevate-zoom
     ng-src="{{small_image}}"
     zoom-image="{{large_image}}" />
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.attr('data-zoom-image',attrs.zoomImage);
      $(element).elevateZoom();
    }
  };
});
```

When using directly `data-zoom-image='{{large_image}}'`, was causing that elevateZoom to try to get the value from that attribute and it was '{{large_image}}' at the time of running the plugin `$(element).elevateZoom();`

[image]

Check the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GRjMPmTbuTQ1rriRzqjg)

---

**UPDATED**

Since there could be cases when the attrs need for the plugin are delayed, you'll need to [$observe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes) the attr and only when its actually ready you call the plugin.

```
app.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // Watch for changes on the attribute before
      // calling the function.
      attrs.$observe('zoomImage', function() {
        linkElevateZoom();
      });

      function linkElevateZoom() {
        // Check that it's not empty.
        if (!attrs.zoomImage) return;
        element.attr('data-zoom-image',attrs.zoomImage);
        $(element).elevateZoom();
      }

      linkElevateZoom();
    }
  };
});
```

Check the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Umdvr1aGq7HjV6Enoxv?p=preview)

**Optional**
When using this in conjunction with views, the plugin leaves behind a div layered on top of the view.  Here's a directive to solve that issue.

```
app.directive('zoomContainer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
                var target = element.children('div.zoomContainer').remove();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This directive needs to be applied to the body element.

```
<body zoom-container>
```

Comment: Ok, actually it seems I slight problem with the above. When I store the urls in $scope.data = {large: ..., small: ...} and assign them after data has loaded, the directive doesn't seem to work any more :(. I've mocked it up at http://plnkr.co/edit/3koXtpAtouVXmnA3HZDW?p=preview and it'd be amazing if you could see whether your solution could be altered to handle this? I've tested and it seems the directive initialises with the data object undefined, so needs to be reinitialised or something?

Comment: I feel from a look over SO and the Angular docs that I maybe need to do something with resolve/promises but I'm not sure how that applies and how to implement it correctly so it plays nice with my directive

Comment: I think will be better to post new question since thats about other issue. Post the link and I can look at it

Comment: @PeterHamilton I saw a comment on my inbox notification, but I cannot see it here: "Fair point. I think this stackoverflow.com/questions/17932736/… or stackoverflow.com/quest..." Did you delete it? Let me know if you still need help, since I was just waiting you to post the question and tell explain about that problem. cheers

Comment: I thought I'd found the solution, but actually it didn't solve my issue. I might write another question but in essence you can see my issue here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3koXtpAtouVXmnA3HZDW?p=preview but I'm not really sure what my question is... :)

Comment: The problem is that when you are calling the plugin "$(element).elevateZoom();" the attr needed isn't ready yet, so you'll need to wait till the attr is ready and only then execute the plugin

Comment: @PeterHamilton I updated the answer and your new plunker, that should help you. Cheers

Comment: Can you please help me with an example of arbor or something similar in angularjs for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974334/need-hierarchical-tree-visualization-in-angularjs)?