# AngularJS Directive for ElevateZoom jQuery Plugin - With Gallery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a extension of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353124/angularjs-directive-for-elevatezoom-jquery-plugin):

The same solution is provided, but with a different scenario:

`ElevateZoom` with gallery. I have this scenario:

```
<img elevate-zoom ng-src="{{small_image}}" zoom-image="{{large_image}}" />
<div id="gallery">
 <a href="" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gallery track by $index" data-image="{{value.small_image}}" data-zoom-image="{{value.large_image}}">
    <img ng-src="{{value.small_image}}" style="height: auto; width: 100px" />
  </a>
</div>
```

With this directive, basically the same one:

```
angular.module('app.directives.elevateZoom',[]).
directive('elevateZoom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  //Will watch for changes on the attribute
  attrs.$observe('zoomImage',function(){
    linkElevateZoom();
  })

  function linkElevateZoom(){
    //Check if its not empty
    if (!attrs.zoomImage) return;
    console.log(attrs.zoomImage);
    element.attr('data-zoom-image',attrs.zoomImage);
    $(element).elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery'});
  }
  linkElevateZoom();
}
  };
    });
```

So, I just created the gallery according to the example on the website and set the parameter to use the gallery - But this does works. Any idea?

Thanks

Also, if someone need the `parms` on the controller:

```
$scope.small_image = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png'
        $scope.large_image = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image1.jpg';
        $scope.gallery = [
        {
            small_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png',
            large_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image1.jpg'
        },
        {
            small_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image2.png',
            large_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image2.jpg'
        },
        {
            small_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png',
            large_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg'
        },
        {
            small_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image4.png',
            large_image: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image4.jpg'
        },
    ]
```

Comment: My original post has been edited without my permission..how to revert it ?

Comment: Any user can edit posts. http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing